# Error al mostrarse fotos en carrito de compras en laravel

Tags: laravel, tablas

hola tengo una duda en mi programa de carrito no muestra las fotos de los libros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que no se que en la tabla de los productos la imagen esta como string

```
  */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('imagePath');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('price');
        });
    }
```

en la bd el campo foto esta como varchar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando le pongo links de jpg no me muestra las fotos.

Respuesta 1:

codigo html

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

   <section class="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Compra aqui</h1>
    </div>

</section>

<div class="container">
<div id="item-lists">
  {{$products->links()}}

    <div class="row">
 
        @foreach($products as $product)
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="{{url('/image/'.$product->imagePath)}}" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{$product->title}}</h3>
        <p>{{$product->description}}</p>
         <a class="pull-left"><b>{{$product->price}}<sup>$</sup></b></a>
         <div id="product">
         @if(array_search($product->id , explode(',' , Cookie::get('product'))) === false )
         <a   class="btn btn-success pull-right id " id ="{{$product->id}}" role="button">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Agregar al carrito</a>
          @else
          <a   class="btn btn-success pull-right remove"
           id ="{{$product->id}}" role="button">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-lg " aria-hidden="true"></i> Removar del carrito</a>
          @endif
         </div>
               <!--   <a href="{{url('/add-cart/'.$product->id)}}" class="btn btn-success pull-right"
         role="button">Add to cart</a>  -->
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

@endforeach
</div>
  {{$products->links()}}
</div>
</div>


@endsection


@section('footer')
```

y las fotos estan guardadas en public image

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podria llamar las imagenes guardadas en la carpeta public/images a la base de datos probe insertandole links pero no me sirvio.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código html,  y la ruta de laravel donde se guardan tus imágenes.

Comment: Lo pusiste en una etiqueta <img>? y como dice @GFlores98 necesitamos ver como mandas a llamar tus datos a la vista

Comment: pude arreglarlo mostre mis imagenes guardadas cambiando esto en el codigo     <img src="{{ asset('image/java.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="...">              se muestra bien gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Coloca tú comentario como respuesta y luego marcala. resuelta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cambie esto en el codigo

```
<img src="{{ asset('image/java.png') }}" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
```

y funciono

Comment: Claro, con {{ asset('image/'.$product->imagePath) }} funciona.